# BeautifulSoup - How to extract text after specified string

Tags: python, python-3.x, beautifulsoup, extract

I have HTML like:

```
<tr>
    <td>Title:</td>
    <td>Title value</td>
</tr>
```

I have to specify after which `<td>` with text i want to grab text of second `<td>`. Something like: Grab text of first next `<td>` after `<td>` which contain text `Title:`. Result should be: `Title value`

I have some basic understanding of Python and BeutifulSoupno  and i have no idea how can I do this when there is no `class` to specify.

I have tried this:

```
row =  soup.find_all('td', string='Title:')
text = str(row.nextSibling)
print(text)
```

and I receive error: AttributeError: `'ResultSet' object has no attribute 'nextSibling'`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First of all, `soup.find_all()` returns a `ResultSet` which contains all the elements with tag `td` and string as `Title:` .

For each such element in the result set , you will need to get the nextSibling separately (also, you should loop through until you find the nextSibling of tag `td` , since you can get other elements in between (like a NavigableString)).

Example -

```
>>> from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
>>> s="""<tr>
...     <td>Title:</td>
...     <td>Title value</td>
... </tr>"""
>>> soup = BeautifulSoup(s,'html.parser')
>>> row =  soup.find_all('td', string='Title:')
>>> for r in row:
...     nextSib = r.nextSibling
...     while nextSib.name != 'td' and nextSib is not None:
...             nextSib = nextSib.nextSibling
...     print(nextSib.text)
...
Title value
```

---

Or you can use another library that has support for XPATH , and with Xpath you can do this easily. Other libraries like - `lxml` or `xml.etree` .

Answer (score 0):

What you're intending to do is relatively easier with lxml using xpath. You can try something like this,

```
from lxml import etree
tree = etree.parse(<your file>)
path_list = tree.xpath('//<xpath to td>')
for i in range(0, len(path_list)) :
    if path_list[i].text == '<What you want>' and i != len(path_list) :
        your_text = path_list[i+1].text
```

Comment: BTW , your xpath is wrong, you are taking the child `td` of the `td` with text as `Title:`. That is not what the op wants, the op wants the next element after that td .

Comment: @AnandSKumar Oh, I'm sorry, didn't notice that, thanks for pointing out! :)