# Python - Using wildcard string matching to extract float from a website's source code

Tags: python, regex, string-matching

I'm working on some code using a web scraper in Python.

Given a website's source code, I need to extract relevant data points. The source code looks like this.

```
</sup>73.00</span> </td> </tr> <tr class="highlight"> <td><span class="data_lbl">Average</span></td> <td> <span class="data_data"><sup>
</sup>86.06</span> </td> </tr> <tr> <td><span class="data_lbl">Current Price</span></td> <td> <span class="data_data"><sup> </sup>83.20</span> </td>
 </tr> </tbody> </table> </div> </div> <!--data-module-name="quotes.module.researchratings.Module"--> </div> <div class="column at8-
col4 at16-col4 at12-col6" id="adCol"> <div intent in-at4units-prepend="#adCol" in-at8units-prepend="#adCol" in-at12units-prepend="#adCol
```

Here is the regex I'm using

```
regex = re.compile('Average*</sup>.....')
```

Which aims to get the 5 characters after the first "/sup" tag encountered after "Average", which in this case would be "86.06" (although I need to clean up the match before I'm left with just a float).

Is there a more elegant way of doing this that outputs the first float encountered after seeing the string "Average".

I'm very new to using regex and apologize if the question isn't clear enough.

Comment: "Is there a more eleagant way of doing this" <- yes, use a html parser, don't summon Cthulhu.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [RegEx match open tags except XHTML self-contained tags](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags)

Comment: Possibly answered here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31638311/beautifulsoup-how-to-extract-text-after-specified-string

Comment: [Do. Not. Parse. HTML. With. Regex.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1732454)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've been able to achieve that using **lookbehind assertions** combined with **ungreedy** search:

`(?<=Average).*?(?<=<\/sup>)([0-9.]{5})`

This working example [here](https://regex101.com/r/enIqJA/6)

**Explanation**

- `([0-9.]{5})`: look for 5 chars combining 0 to 9 and dot, after three following points.

  1. `(?<=Average)`: the word *Average* must appear before
  2. `.*?`: any amount of chars between. Non-greedy (will match as less chars as possible)
  3. `(?<=<\/sup>)`: the tag `</sup>` must appear before

The number you're looking for will be in the **first capture group**

Comment: BTW, i recently see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags) post, i think is mandatory reading